# Exporting Table data to Excel.

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a table (which is return value of so many procedures) in SQL SERVER.

Now I need to give that table data to the customer in **Excel format every day at 12.00 am**.
(need to write a job..Excel sheet should have over written data every day..old data should be deleted)

I have tried **BCP**.. but it is not giving perfect o/p..(like **Header(column name)s are missing**)

Can Anyone help me.... I am using **SQL SERVER Express Edition**

Comment: Which programming language do you know? For Example, if you have Qlikview you can schedule a report, or with Java and Apache POI also you can do this..

Comment: Other option is you can use SSIS package and schedule it's in sql job.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using sql express you can't use SSIS which would be the obvious choice and the simplest.

This code should get you started if you are using c#

```
public void Exel2Sql()
{

    string connString = @"server=myComputerName\sqlexpress;database=myDb;uid=sa;pwd=myPwd;";
    string excelConnString = @"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=c:\temp\my.xls";
    using (var excelConn = new OdbcConnection(excelConnString))
    {
        var command = new OdbcCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConn);
        excelConn.Open();

        using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MyDatabaseTableName";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
            }
            dataReader.Close();
        }
        excelConn.Close();
    }


}
```